# Series circuit of capacitor and ohmic resistance: Voltage drop at Capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, voltage

I have a question to an exercise I am currently trying to solve.

It is given an Capacitor and an ohmic resistance in a series circuit. The whole voltage is 40V, the resistor has an resistance of 10kΩ. The solution of the exercise says, that the voltage drop at the capacitor is 40V (and you can therefore calculate the carge with the given capacity Q=C*U). But now my question is: Is there really no voltage drop at the resistor? And Why?
The whole circuit is DC.

[image]

Sorry for my bad english, I am an German student.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hint: the voltage drop across a resistor is $V=IR$. What is the current $I$ in the circuit?

Comment: Thanks, I am afraid to break the rules - but I have no clue to go on. Sorry. The current _I_ is not given (and I can't calculate it through U=IR, because R of the whole circuit with the capacitor is for me unknown).

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us write down the equation of motion for the given RC circuit. Using Kirchhoff's voltage law we have $U=iR+\frac{q}{C}$, where $i$ is the charging current in the circuit at time $t$, $q$ represents the charge stored in the capacitor at time $t$. Initially(at t=0), $q=0$ and $i$ is a maximum.**The charging current decreases with time because of a build-up of charge in the capacitor**. The current $i$ is equal to $\frac{dq}{dt}$. The equation of motion can now be written as $U=R\frac{dq}{dt}+\frac{q}{C}$. This is a first-order differential equation whose solution is $q(t)=CU(1-e^{-t/RC})$. If you examine the solution you will see that when t is long enough, the quantity $e^{-t/RC}$ becomes negligible as compared to 1. In that situation, the charge in the capacitor after a sufficiently long time will be $q=CU$. If we differentiate the above solution for q with respect to time we get $i=\frac{dq}{dt}=\frac{U}{R}e^{-t/RC}$. This equation tells us that after a sufficiently long time the current in the circuit will be equal to zero, again because the quantity $e^{-t/RC}$ becomes almost zero. So after a sufficiently long time the current in the circuit is zero and the charge in the capacitor is $q=CU$.

**You can arrive at the same answer in the following manner:** At t=0, the charge on the capacitor is zero. So the net potential difference in the circuit is $U$, the supply voltage. So the current at t=0 is a maximum and is equal to $\frac{U}{R}$. With the passage of time, the current decreases because of a build up of charge in the capacitor. This charge in the capacitor causes a potential difference across it that opposes the applied potential difference $U$. As a result the current decreases and finally when the voltage across the capacitor is equal to the applied potential difference $U$, the current in the circuit is zero and so there is no voltage drop across the resistor and the voltage across the capacitor is equal to $U$. So, finally the charge in the capacitor is $q=CU$.

Comment: Tanks a lot! This aspect I had totally forgotten...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that initially the capacitor was uncharged.
A current would flow in the circuit which would charge the capacitor.

The maximum voltage that the capacitor or the resistor can have across them is the voltage of the battery which is 40 V.

The sum of the voltages across the capacitor and the resistor must equal the voltage of the battery.

No matter how strange it may seem if the voltage across the capacitor is 40 V what must be the voltage across the resistor?  (Look at your diagram).

What does that tell you about the current in the circuit?

Is the capacitor still being charged?